# To set height an width to the img

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code I want to set height and width to 50 px to this image.

Please help me to do this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "InvoiceDetailsNew2.aspx/GenerateNewBarcodeImage",
    data: "{'BarCodeNumber':'" + Barcode + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var orders = JSON.parse(data.d);
        //alert(data);
        var height = 50;
        alert(orders);
        //imgContent = orders;
        imgContent = "<img "


         + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64,"
         + orders + "'/>";
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error in Product Loading");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "InvoiceDetailsNew2.aspx/GenerateNewBarcodeImage",
                data: "{'BarCodeNumber':'" + Barcode + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var orders = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    //alert(data);
                    var height = 50;
                    var width= 50;
                    alert(orders);
                    //imgContent = orders;
                    imgContent = "<img height='"+height+ "' width='"+width+"'"


                     + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64,"
                     + orders + "'/>";
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error in Product Loading");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:-

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "InvoiceDetailsNew2.aspx/GenerateNewBarcodeImage",
        data: "{'BarCodeNumber':'" + Barcode + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        width: "50",
        height:"50",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var orders = JSON.parse(data.d);
            //alert(data);
            var height = 50;
            alert(orders);
            //imgContent = orders;
            imgContent = "<img " + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64," + orders + "'/>";
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error in Product Loading");
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline style while creating the image tag.

```
imgContent = "<img "   
    + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64,"
    + orders + 
    + " height='50' width='50'" + "'/>";
```

---

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "InvoiceDetailsNew2.aspx/GenerateNewBarcodeImage",
  data: "{'BarCodeNumber':'" + Barcode + "'}",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var orders = JSON.parse(data.d);
    //alert(data);
    var height = 50;
    alert(orders);
    //imgContent = orders;
    imgContent = "<img "   
    + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64,"
    + orders + 
    + " height='50' width='50'" + "'/>";
  },
  error: function (result) {
    alert("Error in Product Loading");
  }
});
```

Comment: image is not displaying when setting height and width

Answer (score -1):

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "InvoiceDetailsNew2.aspx/GenerateNewBarcodeImage",
                    data: "{'BarCodeNumber':'" + Barcode + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var orders = JSON.parse(data.d);
                        //alert(data);
                        var height = 50;
                        alert(orders);
                        //imgContent = orders;
                        imgContent = "<img "


                         + "src='" + "data:image/jpg;base64,"
                         + orders + "'/>";

   $(imgContent).height(50).width(50); // set using jquery methods
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error in Product Loading");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Could you please fiddle it